# Array of Variable size in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am trying to write code that uses a variable array for some computations.I am having a bit of trouble with declaring the array for this. currently I have

```
    Generic(Y: integer:= ) ;---enter array width
    Z: integer:=  );---enter array height 
    | ----some code left out
    |
    type test is array(0 to Z-1) of std_logic_vector(Y-1 
    downto 0 );
```

The problem with this is that when Y is 1, the program gets error saying it cannot understand  '0' and '1' during this assignment.

```
    signal T: test:=('0','1','0','1'); -----for Y=1 and z=4
```

I am assuming it is because I am declaring a STD_logic_vector that is only one bit long,and thus should be std_logic? I am unable to think of an elegant way to remove this problem, and all my google searches for "array of undeclared size VHDL" only give me examples of what I am already doing now. I am new to VHDL so please any help would be appreciated.

Also I am a unsure of how I am assigning values to the array. I also tried

```
    signal T: test:=(('0'),('1'),('0'),('1'));
```

but still got an error. some sources say I should assign using "" but the compiler says its incorrect as it is for a string. I am quite confused so please help!

Comment: "*I am assuming it is because I am declaring a STD_logic_vector that is only one bit long,and thus should be std_logic?*" No, the type of the aggregate element expression must be convertible to the type of the array element e.g. `signal T: test :=  ("0", "1", "0", "1");`. Double quotes where these are string literals with a length of one. The type of the aggregate and it's elements comes from context (the type mark test). Show a [mcve] with actual error messages. "I also tried" wouldn't work, aggregates with a single element must use named association `((0 => '0'), (0 => '1'),`...

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.2 Literals, para 5 "...The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type...." (std_logic_vector is a resolved std_ulogic_vector, an array type whose std_ulogic elements are  of a character enumeration type). 15.7 String literals, para 4 "The length of a string literal is the number of character values in the sequence represented. ..."

Comment: 15.6 Character literals "A character literal is formed by enclosing one of the 191 graphic characters (including the space and nonbreaking space characters) between two apostrophe characters. A character literal has a value that belongs to a character type." 5.2.2 Enumeration types, 5.2.2.1 General, para 4 "An enumeration type is said to be a character type if at least one of its enumeration literals is a character literal." And we see a character literal is not a value of an array type.

Comment: 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General, para 4 ",,,Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions."

Comment: You should use a function to compute complex init values.

Comment: @user1155120 unfortunately as I started programming a few weeks ago I'm not sure what two thirds of your comment means, '-_-  but as you confirmed it had to be ("0","1","0","1"), I messed around with my code a bit more and the compiler accepted that. the problem I had previously when i tried assigning with "" is probably cause i did it like this (("0"),("1"),("0"),("1")), so thank you very much! now to google what a literal means

Comment: The definition of literal used in VHDL comes from it's precursor Ada83(Annex D) - "Literal. A literal represents a value literally, that is, by means of letters and other characters. A literal is either a numeric literal, an enumeration literal, a character literal, or a string literal." Noting VHDL adds bit string literal (which has an equivalent string literal value). These are all lexical elements. To add confusion there's also physical literals comprised of two lexical elements, a numeric literal and a unit identifier.